# Texture glitches and artifacts when camera is far away?

Tags: modeling, rendering, materials

From up close the mesh in the view port looks fine. But when the camera moves away, artifacts and glitches appear? Is this a topology issue or a rendering issue in Blender? The object has no UV texture applied as each mesh has a material node assigned to it

[image]

Up close no mesh errors... Moving the camera back though, render glitches and artifacts pop up as the camera looks at the item

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Is the decal a separate geometry from the disk itself? If so, have a look at this article:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-fighting

Comment: Thank you, this was the problem... After applying a shrinkwrap modifier, the problem was solved.

Comment: If the user's post was helpful, you might consider marking it as the thread solution.